# iterate objects in java 8 streams

Tags: mongodb, lambda, java-8, spring-data, java-stream

I'd like to iterate the following mongo db collection in java8

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59d1dc99a1a79605342f15a7"), "_class" : "com.test.User", "vehicle" : [ { "name" : "aaa", "color" : "blue" } ], "count" : 1,"createdBy" : "Admin", "lastModifiedBy" : "Admin" }
```

Expected O/P fields:

_id,name,color,count,createdBy

I tried the below

```
queryvalue.stream().flatMap(vehicle->vehicle.getVehicles().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

queryvalue is the one where i'm pulling the data from spring mongo db repository. I'm new to java8 pls help.

Below are the classes:

```
Class User{
@CreatedDate
protected DateTime createdDate;
@LastModifiedDate
protected DateTime lastModifiedDate;
List<Vehicle> vehicle;
public void setCreatedDate(DateTime createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }
public String getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }   
public List<Vehicle> getVehicles() {
        return vehicle;
    }
public void setVehicle(List<Vehicle> vehicle) {
        this.vehicle= vehicle;
    }
-- similarly for lastModifieddate and comments etc--    
}

Class Vehicle{
private String name;
private string color;
public void setColor(String color){
this.color = color;
return this;
}
public String getColor(){
return color;
}
public void setName(String name){
this.name = name;
return this;
}
public void getName(){
return name;
}
}
```

And am pulling using this:

```
List<Vehicle>queryvalue  = repository.findByVehicleName(vehiclename);
```

Comment: this is really un-clear, can you may show your classes?

Comment: What is your need / problem ? 
You have the list of result in your queryValue, just iterate on it ? 
No need for stream if you don't want to convert/filter/etc...